# A lot of MSI###.tmp folders in drive d

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, temporary-files

I have a problem. When I open drive D: I see a lot of MSI#####.tmp folders

[image]

I tried to delete them but I got an error:

> "You must have administrator permissions"

Worse, the tmp folders are being created all the time; it's not stopping...

How can I solve it?

Comment: Man, go to http://www.sysinternals.com/ and get Sysinternals Suite. So open Process Explorer then go to 'Options > VirusTotal > Check' and see if in VirusTotal column something is in red (you must have internet connection). If so, your computer is infected with some viruses. If infected, use 'File > Save as', save the text file, copy and paste its contents here and let's see what is the problem...